# Jenkins works 20 minutes per tested class?

Tags: performance, selenium, jenkins, junit, jenkins-cli

I have a specific problem with my Jenkins on local machine. I started testing my project java classes on Jenkins and when everything is fine (without errors) it complete it in 1 minute or under it. Problem is in case when class has some kind of error (ex: Button name doesn't exist ) Jenkins freeze up and blue cicrle spin for 20-30min and then JUnit show me report and build fails. How can I speed it up?

Comment: Do you have a report with timings / timestamps that we can see? Are you doing any explicit waits in your test?

Comment: 17:33:04 TestCreateClass:
17:33:05     [junit] Running com.mallocinc.ytm.testing.tests.courses.TestCreateClass
17:56:37     [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1,411.97 sec
17:56:37     [junit] Output:
17:56:37     [junit] 45seconds passed.
17:56:37     [junit] 
17:56:37     [junit] Test com.mallocinc.ytm.testing.tests.courses.TestCreateClass FAILED

Comment: There is time report, I do only thread waits but they are few sec only.

Comment: Maybe add some trace logging? But I wonder if you've got some explicit waits with very long timeouts that are masking some other problem on that environment.

Comment: For that class specific problem is button that doesn't exist. (I did that on purpose to test time)